# Animating 3 images in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I need to animate 3 images of clouds in canvas, they should be moving on X axis and once they disappear on the right side they should reappear on the left. Each cloud should be on different X and Y axis starting positions and they should be moving with different speed.

First I tried to create only 1 cloud animation and this is what I came up with:

```
var canvas, context, docWidth, docHeight;

window.onload = function(){
    docWidth = window.innerWidth;
    docHeight =  window.innerHeight
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    resizeCanvas(docWidth, docHeight);
    drawCloud(0, 0, docWidth, docHeight);
}

function resizeCanvas(width, height){
    canvas.width = docWidth;
    canvas.height = docHeight;
}

function drawCloud(x,y,width, height){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'images/cloud1.png';

    img.onload = function(){
        context.save();
        context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
        imageWidth = img.naturalWidth;
        imageHeight = img.naturalHeight;
        context.drawImage(img,x-imageWidth,10);
        context.restore();

        if(x >= width+imageWidth){
            x=0-imageWidth/2;
        } else {
            x += 3;
        }
        var loopTimer = setTimeout('drawCloud('+x+','+y+','+width+','+height+')',24);
    }
}
```

This works just fine, I see the cloud animation, it disappears on the right side and reappears on the left. Now with 3 images that's where things get complicated. I tried an OOP approach:

First in my Canvas element I tried to preload images:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="0px" height="0px">
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
        var images = new Array()
        function preload() {
            for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                images[i] = new Image()
                images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
            }
        }
        preload(
            "images/cloud1.png",
            "images/cloud2.png",
            "images/cloud3.png"
        )
    //--><!]]>
</script>
</canvas>
```

Then I tried to create the Cloud objects:

```
function Cloud (x, y, width, height, filename, velocity, rate) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.filename = filename;
    this.velocity = velocity;
    this.rate = rate;
}

Cloud.prototype = {
    constructor:Cloud,
    moveCloud:function(imageWidth){
        if(x >= width+imageWidth){
            x=0-imageWidth/2;
        } else {
            x += velocity;
        }
    },
    getFilename:function(){
        return this.filename;
    },
    getX:function(){
        return this.x;
    },
    getY:function(){
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

Then this drawing function:

```
function drawCloud(clouds, width, height){
    var img;
    var arrLength = clouds.length;

        context.save();
        context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
        for(var i=0; i<arrLength; i++){
            var Cloud = clouds[i];
            img = new Image();
            img.src = Cloud.getFilename();
            imageWidth = img.naturalWidth;
            imageHeight = img.naturalHeight;
            context.drawImage(img, Cloud.getX()-imageWidth, Cloud.getY());
            clouds[i].moveCloud(imageWidth);
        }

        context.restore();

        var loopTimer = setTimeout('drawCloud('+clouds+', '+width+', '+height+')',24);

}
```

And finally I call for this function in my `window.onload`:

```
var canvas, context, docWidth, docHeight;

window.onload = function(){
    docWidth = window.innerWidth;
    docHeight =  window.innerHeight
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    resizeCanvas(docWidth, docHeight);

    var cloud1 = new Cloud(0, 10, docWidth, docHeight, 'images/cloud1.png', 3, 24);
    var cloud2 = new Cloud(400, 10, docWidth, docHeight, 'images/cloud2.png', 5, 24);
    var cloud3 = new Cloud(160, 10, docWidth, docHeight, 'images/cloud3.png', 1, 24);
    var clouds = [cloud1, cloud2, cloud3];
    drawCloud(clouds, docWidth, docHeight);
}
```

Now I don't even see the clouds images on canvas, not to mention their animation. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: It would be nice to create a jsfiddle, too much code to read

Comment: @Variant I tried to create jsfiddle, but it doesn't even show me the canvas element: http://jsfiddle.net/z3azsn5a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I improved your fiddel and made it work: http://jsfiddle.net/z3azsn5a/3/

There were a few things I had to fix, you can compare your original source to mine but the most important ones were:

1. setTimeOut should get a function not a built string with parameters
2. You redefined `Cloud` in an inner scope, not sure this was causing any problem but it's a bad practice.
3. there was javascript inside the `canvas` element
4. the jsfiddle was configured to have the code inside the onload event and you declared that event yourself, thus your window.onload was not running

Comment: Great, it works, thank you very much! 2 more question though: 1) the code in `canvas` element was supposed to preload the images before they can be output to canvas; though I can it's working without the code, but still, don't I have to preload images before outputing them to canvas? 2) When you say `You redefined Cloud in an inner scope`, do you refer to this line: `constructor:Cloud` or something else? I'm new to JS OOP and read this in a few tutorials, so I'll be glad to have some explanation.

Comment: You don't have to preload the images, it can be a good practice to do so if you want the initial drawing to start at a later time and you have time to preload. As for the redefine, i was talking about this: `var Cloud = clouds[i];`

Comment: Got it! And about the redefine - yes, my bad, wrote it as class instead of variable unintentionally. Again, thank you very much! Appreciate it!